# ¿Porqué al llamar un JPanel a un JFrame no se pasa el contenido del JPanel?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en *JAVA*, tengo un *JPanel* dentro de una clase, que contiene sus características, luego fuera del paquete tengo un *JFrame* donde también está el *main*, al llamar al *JPanel* desde la clase principal si se pasa en *JPanel*, pero no con sus características.

Este es el código del JFrame, donde está también el main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import VentanaPrincipal.VentanaPrincipal;/*importación de la ventana*/

public class Funcionamiento {
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    VentanaPrincipal vp = new VentanaPrincipal();
    public void initComponents(){
        //Características del frame
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Creador de Documentos");
        frame.setLocation(250, 100);
        frame.add(vp);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
       Funcionamiento cf = new Funcionamiento();
       cf.initComponents();
    }
    
    
}
```

Este es el *JPanel*:

```
package VentanaPrincipal;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;


public class VentanaPrincipal extends JPanel{
    /*public JPanel ventana = new JPanel();*/
    public void VentanaPropiedades(){
       this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       this.setSize(800, 500);
       this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

El *JPanel* al llamarlo si se pasa, pero en blanco, he visto que se puede usar una función llamada *container* que creo que funcionaria con eso pero no se cómo usarla.

> **DP:** Estoy usando NetBeans.

Comment: Lo que veo es que no estas llamando al método `VentanaPropiedades()` que es el que aplica las características que esperas ver en el panel; simplemente llamalo desde el `initComponents()`

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y quita la etiqueta netbeans, el lenguaje es agnóstico del editor de texto, esa etiqueta debería ser usada con problemas relacionados al IDE (como configuraciones)

Answer (score 0):

No agregaste las propiedades en el constructor de la clase, creaste un método para dárselas, pero no lo llamaste.

Las propiedades van en el constructor de la clase para que se agreguen, o se pueden separar por métodos para ir creando el panel, lo cosa esta en llamarlos desde el constructor.

Tu código funciona si agregas las propiedades en el constructor

```
public VentanaPrincipal() {
    this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    this.setSize(800, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

O llamando al metodo de las propiedades desde el consturctor de la clase

```
public VentanaPrincipal() {
    VentanaPropiedades();
}

/*public JPanel ventana = new JPanel();*/
public void VentanaPropiedades(){
   this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
   this.setSize(800, 500);
   this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Gracias! si me funcionó, no sabia lo que era lo de llamar al constructor.

Comment: Recuerda marcar como solución la respuesta , revisa [tour].